# Magento order mail are not going to customer?

Tags: magento

My magento site stoped sending the order mail to customer, i have checked several answer, but nothing works for me.
I tried to send mail with php mail funtion, its working but mail going to spam also. Is this may be a reason?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

This may be a server fault, it may be an issue of server mail configuration. Try to install some SMTP mail extension, it will be helpful for you. Also check if there any new installation of extension which causing problem

Answer (score 0):

If mails are going to spam, then there may be chances of mis configuration in server, alternatively you can install the below extension & configure in backend , than mails will go to inbox....

https://github.com/aschroder/Magento-SMTP-Pro-Email-Extension

http://www.aschroder.com/product/smtppro-magento-smtp-email/